# Windows RegEdit hides and protects entries

Tags: windows, registry, file-association

I'd like to **reset a file association**, created using the "Open With" dialog.
I am on **Windows 7** ULT.
I have associated *.part files with VLC.exe an I can see that this association is accomplished by a special "**UserChoice**" entry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.part`.
However I can only see this by a special registry search tool that browses the registry keys and values using the Win32 API. I can not see the entry in the "Windows Registry Editor" aka **RegEdit**.
Regedit indirectly knows this key, because if I try an create a new reg key with the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.part` RegEdit says that the key .part already exists (which is true).
Also I can delete this key using the cmdline tool **reg.exe** by:
`reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.part" /f /va`
If the key wouldn't exist reg.exe would print out an err msg.
Anyhow the key isn't really actually deleted because I can repeat the command over and over again which indicates that the key is still there. Also in Windows Explorer if I select a *.part file and check the file association it says it's still associated with VLC.exe. So it seems to be recretaed immediately anytime i gtes deleted, which indicates a protection mechanism.
So the simple questions is:
How can I really delete this Registry entry and how can I reset this file association?
And, optionally, how can I make RegEdit display it?
I do not want to change it using the "Open With" dialog, because it would create yet another UserChoice entry under ...FileExt.part
But my goal is to **add multiple Commands to .part files** that I can select with the right click context menu.
This used to work by simply associating the extension with a progid and adding the commands you want to the ProgId's *Shell* subkey. 
Any one any clues?

Comment: I know this isn't going to help, but, I was able to create the key and a sub key in Win10 Home. Looking up .part points the type to a partial file that gets created in a download with a few select programs like Mozilla. Just curious why you want to use this ext over something else.

Comment: Other programs that use the *.part extension for partial downloads also store meta data information in files with the (dual) extension *.part.met.
I have a script that extracts and displays the meta data I am interested in from the *.part.met file and I want to associate this script with the *.part file. 
It used to work adding sth like "HKCR\Part_auto_file\Shell\ExtractMeta\Command"
But this "UserChoice" thing and the entries it creates disable this standard mechanism for associating Commands to file extensions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth...
I finally found the reason why the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.part` was not displayed in my local RegEdit install.
And why I thus could not modify / delete it using RegEdit.

For whatever reason in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\` I had **reg sub keys with square brackets in their name**, like:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.02]`

Since RegEdit seems to use this character as a meta character to denote the end of a key name, it didn't seem to have managed displaying all subsequent subkeys properly. It only showed those that alphabetically came before the first key with a ']' in its name.

I realized this by exporting the whole `FileExt` key into a reg file.
And I also could remove these junk entries with a reg file.
As for how to delete reg entries using reg files see: [How to delete registry subkeys using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310516/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg#delete)

So now I finally could add the additional entries to the `part_auto_file` key
and the show up in the context menu and even execute. Cheerio.